# Why does an integral extension over a ring has the same Krull dimension as the ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

The Krull dimension of a ring R is defined as the supremum of the lengths of chains of prime ideals contained in R. I heard that an integral extension over a ring R has the same Krull dimension as R, however, I don't really see why this is true.

Comment: You can find this in most commutative algebra books. Key words are going up and going down, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Was looking for it in Atiyah-Macdonald and couldn't find it, not even as an exercise... I guess they find too obvious :) For future reference, we can combine Corollary 4.9 (incomparability of distinct primes lying above the same prime) and Theorem 5.11 (going-up) to get the result.

Answer (score 7):

The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element#Integral_extensions) hints that an integral extension $R\subseteq S$ satisfies going-up, lying-over and incomparability, the Krull dimensions of $R$ and $S$ are the same.